# How to display folder and item in a treeview (inside a listview)

Tags: list-view, folder

First of all, thank you for reading this!

I have a custom list with folders and items in them. What I'm looking for is a webpart or view that shows the list in a treeview. An example for that is the navigation on the right side. I dont want to have it on the right side, it should be in the center instead of the listview.

Do you have any hints for me?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://treeviewwebpart.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/librarytreewebpart.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Tree_View_for_List.aspx